# Appending XML element as a text node (escaped)

Tags: java, xml

I need to take a XML element and its children, escape the XML and append them as a text node in another document. I know this approach is stupid, but an API requires it.

Could I accomplish this using one of many XML libraries for Java? 
I tried using JAXP, but my code doesn't escape apostrophes and double quotes.

```
    …
    String content = elementToString(nodeToEscape);
    Text text = document.createTextNode(content);
    Node n = document.getElementsByTagName("targetNode").item(0);
    n.appendChild(text);
}

String elementToString(Element element) {
    Document document = element.getOwnerDocument();
    DOMImplementationLS domImplLS = (DOMImplementationLS) document.getImplementation();
    LSSerializer serializer = domImplLS.createLSSerializer();
    return serializer.writeToString(element);
}
```

Resulting document fragment:

```
 &lt;dataItem aggregate="none" name="Order number"…
```

Comment: are you sure you need to escape quotes and apostrophes? according to: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp Only the characters "<" and "&" are strictly illegal in XML.

Comment: @gawi: You're right! Care to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to escape quotes and apostrophes. According to: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp Only the characters "<" and "&" are strictly illegal in XML

Answer (score 0):

[dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/) will certainly let you do this. I've had to do very similar things (albeit many years ago) and dom4j was my tool of choice. [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) is an alternative - whichever one you find more intuitive.

Both provide a friendlier object model for XML than JAXP.